# Can i use plywood to build shelves for my stereo speakers?

Tags: framing, plywood

I recently bought a [Creative SBS A120 2.1](https://asia.creative.com/p/speakers/sbs-a120) for my home computer.

Now while the subwoofer would be on the table, I want the tweeters or/and two satellite speakers to be little higher as in two shelves attached to the wall on plywood. I have heard that plywood doesn't resonate or vibrate much which is important as the wall is oldish. Is this true ?

I am looking for ideas as to how to accomplish this ?

Comment: I'm confused. What's the "tweeter" and whats' the "speaker"? Your question isn't clear, though. Accomplish what?

Comment: So... you want to make a small shelf out of plywood?  Sure. Go for it.

Comment: tweeter is the big box and the two satellite speakers are small boxes. If you had looked at the link you would have got it.

Comment: @JPhi1618. actually was looking at two shelves and wanted to ask if anybody had any good ideas. I have edited the question a bit.

Comment: @shirish, the large box is the "Subwoofer" responsible for deep, low frequency sounds like a big dog barking "woof, woof".  "Tweeter" normally refers to small speakers responsible for high-pitched sounds like a bird tweeting.  So, what part of the shelf are you having trouble with?  Be more specific, because shelves are obvious to make, or purchase and install.

Comment: ah, my bad, then the tweeters, the subwoofer would be on the table, thank you.

Comment: subs should be floored. a sub against a floor/wall is 2x as loud as one in the middle. a sub in the wall/floor corner of the room is 2X as loud as one on the floor. a sub in the wall/wall/floor corner is twice as loud...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shirish, The answer is yes you can use plywood if you want, the small speakers are not going to create much vibration.

Your system has three components. two speakers that have handle the mid range and high frequencies and the sub woofer that produces the low frequencies. The speakers, (*the smaller ones*) that typically sit on the desk can be placed on a shelf. The shelf can be made out of plywood or solid wood or particle board, it does not matter to much because your speakers (tweeters and mids ) are not very big and the higher frequencies do not vibrate very much.

The important thing is the the bracket be attached to the wall securely and the shelf material also be attached to the brackets securely. Some speakers have holes on the back so you can hang them on the wall with a mounting system or a even a screw.

Your sub woofer is going be the thing that vibrates things in your house. Low frequency sound will travel though walls and floors. You do not need it on your desk, if fact it may vibrate your desk and the things on it to much. it can be anywhere on the floor. They make special feet for speakers and subs to raise it off of the floor or shelf, these are mainly to optimize sound quality. Test it out and if it vibrating your floor move it around to find a better place. Again the low sounds travel very well so it can be anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Tweeters (most satellite speakers in general) vibrate at very high frequencies which don't transmit through shelves and walls to a problematic degree. Place them on any shelf or other surface as is convenient, or mount them using the 1/4-20 threaded inserts they may have using speaker brackets.